# CNTK classification model Classifies all 1

Tags: cntk

I have a cntk model which takes in features related to clicks and other information and predicts if something would be clicked in the future. Using the same features in a randomforest works fine, however, cntk classifies all 1. Why does this happen? Is there any parameter tuning needed? The features have varying scale. 
My train action looks like this:

```
    BrainScriptNetworkBuilder = [
    inputD = $inputD$
    labelD = $labelD$
    #hidden1 = $hidden1$
    model(features) = {
        w0 = ParameterTensor{(1 : 2), initValueScale=10}; b0 = ParameterTensor{1, initValueScale=10};
        h1 = w0*features + b0; #hidden layer
        z = Sigmoid (h1)
    }.z
    features = Input(inputD)
    labels = Input(labelD)

    z = model(features)
    #now that we have output, find error
    err = SquareError (labels, z)
    lr = Logistic (labels, z)
    output = z

    criterionNodes = (err)
    evaluationNodes = (err)
    outputNodes = (z)
]

SGD = [
    epochSize = 4 #learn
    minibatchSize = 1 #learn
    maxEpochs = 1000 #learn
    learningRatesPerSample = 1
    numMBsToShowResult = 10000
    firstMBsToShowResult = 10
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what KeD said, a random forest does not care about the actual values of the features, only about their relative order.

Unlike trees, neural networks are sensitive to the actual values of the features (rather than just their relative order).

Your input might contain some features with very large values. You should probably recode them. There are different schemes for doing this. One possibility is to subtract the mean from each feature and scale it to -1,1 or divide by it's standard deviation. Another possibility for positive features is a transformation such as f => log(1+f). You could also use a batch normalization layer.

Answer (score 1):

Since your features are of varying scales, I would suggest you normalize the features. You mentioned, cntk classifies all input as 1. I am assuming it happens when you predict using the trained model. But, what happens during training? Can you plot a graph of training + test error on a graph (cntk supports TensorBoard now)? That would give you some indication of if your model is over-fitting. Moreover, as a side not, I would suggest to increase the model's learning capability (most likely, by increasing number of hidden layers) to learn a better distribution of you data.

Comment: Would a batchnormalization layer do z normalization of the features? What kind of normalization can be done?

Comment: I was referring to standardization, i.e. `(x - mean) / std`. However, BatchNormalization can be used to do that and is likely to perform better. It will actually learn the normalization as a part of your model's learning process. As far as I know, it uses mean and variance to normalize the input. However, it has other nice benefits like reducing over-fitting and reducing the need of careful initialization- which is almost always good to have. You can read more detail on it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the learning rate is too high, please try learningRatesPerSample = 0.001